# Joins in conditional statement in SQL Query

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, conditional-statements

I have scenario like, I need to add my join in conditional

e.g. When value is 1 then inner join to table a and if value 2 then inner join to table

below is my sample query and I am getting error **Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'inner'**

```
DECLARE @i INT=1
select name from emp
if(@i=1) 
begin
inner join a on a.ID=emp.ID
end
else if(@i=1) 
begin
inner join b on b.ID=emp.ID
end
where emp.ID=2
```

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Would this work? Outer join both tables in both conditions and put the conditional in your select clause like so:

```
select name, case when @i=1 then a.column else b.column end from emp
left outer join a on a.ID=emp.ID
left outer join b on b.ID=emp.ID
where emp.ID=2
```

Comment: This could produce extra records, because of the extra join.

Answer (score 0):

As you found out the construct is illegal in SQL.  An IF statement cannot be included in a DML query.  One can, however, write **two separate queries** (introducing in the process a bit of duplication) and have one or the other **conditionally selected**.

```
DECLARE @i INT
SET @i=1
if(@i=1) 
  begin
      select name from emp
      inner join a on a.ID=emp.ID
      where emp.ID=2
  end
  else if(@i=2) 
  begin
      select name from emp
      inner join b on b.ID=emp.ID
      where emp.ID=2
  end
```